# Why does AirDrop keep turning itself off?

Tags: airdrop

I have iOS 11.2.2 Installed on an iPhone 8. Periodically, someone will try to send me something via AirDrop and it’s turned off. I NEVER turn it off. I never turn off Bluetooth. I do sometimes turn off Wi-Fi in order to disconnect from my home Wi-Fi when I’m driving away but I turn it back on after. When I find AirDrop turned off, I always turn it back on and then a few days later, I’ll try to use it and it’s off again. What could be causing this??

Comment: What is your AirDrop currently set to (Receiving only, Contacts only, or Everyone)?

Comment: It's set to "Everyone". Checked this morning and it was still on from last night. Not sure what's turning it off.

Comment: I've never seen a phone where this doesn't happen - presumably it's for power saving. I don't understand how it's supposed to work though - for me the recipient never appears until it's manually turned on again.

Comment: Do you use Low Power Mode? According to its description, it stops receiving emails once it's enabled. Maybe it disables AirDrop too.